# Combining Boost, Threads, OpenSSL, and Curl libraries into a one static library

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries

I have created a C++ static library that depends on `Boost`, `OpenSSL`, `CURL`, and `Threads`. My goal is to combine the dependencies into a single static library.

```
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL)
include_directories(/usr/local/include ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
if (CURL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_CURL)
endif()

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} mylib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} TgBot stdc++ ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

I found the dependencies by printing the libraries:

```
message(${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
message(${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
message(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message(${CURL_LIBRARIES})
```

which prints:

```
-lpthread
/usr/lib64/libssl.so
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
Boost::system
/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so
```

I assumed `Boost::system` is `libboost_system.a` and therefore I tried to use `ar` to create an object file for it:

```
ar -x libboost_system.a
```

but it creates an `error_code.o` object.

Could someone kindly let me know if creating a single static library with these dependencies is a doable task?

Comment: `ar -x` will unpack the ar archive = libboost_system.a .... .... which is quite unusual, as files.a usually contains multiple objects.o . .... Example libc.a holds 1578 objects !

Answer (score 2):

The .so extension is an acronym for shared object.
Thus, it is not possible to combine them into a static one.
You need to link against static versions of the libs (.a files).
How to add them to cmake settings is one thing, but first make sure you have them installed.

Comment: If I had `libssl.a`, `libcrypto.a`, `libcurl.a`, would I be able to create a single static library with them in my `CMakeLists.txt`? Please let me know.